# Using Wix 3.8, using Bundle how do Uninstall an ExePackage when the uninstaller is packaged up inside an exe installer?

Tags: c#, wix

I've looked around at several answers here on StackOverflow and I couldn't find exactly what I needed to resolve an issue I am currently facing

I'm using Wix 3.8 and Visual Studio 2008, and having created an XML deployment project the Bundle.wxs file looks like this.

Here's my Bundle.wxs file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" >

    <Bundle Name="SomeCompanyBundle"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="Some Company"
          UpgradeCode="348d9d7c-6a37-44cd-8054-61b97777b5bd" 
          IconSourceFile="..\Some Company\logo_64.ico">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
        LicenseFile="..\Some Company\license-agreement.rtf"
        LogoFile="..\Some Company\logo_64.png" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <ExePackage Id="EXE_UsbDriversInstallerExe"
                  DisplayName="Driver Installer Executable" 
                  Compressed="yes"
                  Cache="yes"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Permanent="no"
                  Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="..\Some Company\Drivers-Installer.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/SILENT=YES"
                  />


        <!-- More MsiPackages are used in real Bundle.wxs, but they aren't included in this question, because they are working on install and uninstall -->
    </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

This creates a Bundle installation file, called SomeCompanyBundle.exe

I can install this bundle via the command prompt e.g. SomeCompanyBundle.exe /quiet /install i.e. no install GUI is shown.

The issue I have is on the Uninstall which is due to the limited command line options given by Drivers-Installer.exe (This is an old installer.exe file from a third party company that no exists)

The only options available are SILENT=(YES/NO) or LANG=(ENGLISH, SPANISH....).

This Drivers-Installer.exe doesn't allow an Uninstall action.  It has an Uninstall.exe program bundled inside the Drivers-Installer.exe and this Uninstall.exe is only available upon successful installation of Drivers-Installer.exe

The Uninstall.exe, once installed, is always located in the full path c:\Program Files(x 86)\SomeThirdPartyCompany\Drivers-Installed\Uninstall.exe

So how do I run this Uninstall.exe, when I need to uninstall the SomeCompanyBundle.exe when I use command prompt to run SomeCompanyBundle.exe /quiet /uninstall

The solutions I have tried are:

1) UninstallCommand="SILENT=YES" ---- Did not work, due to the above.

2) CustomAction ----- Got confused about how to run the Uninstall.exe just on the Bundle uninstall action.

3) Played around with uil:DirectorySearch and util:RegistrySearch. Again I got confused about how to run the Uninstall.exe just on the Bundle uninstall action.

Any help with examples/explanation will be appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an interesting way you can do this. I did something similar where I have an install that, when installed, puts an "uninstall.exe" somewhere on the system that you run to uninstall the product.

Use a util:FileSearch for seeing if that product is installed.

```
<util:FileSearch 
    Id="UsbDriversDirSearch"
    Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]\SomeThirdPartyCompany\Drivers-Installed\Uninstall.exe"
    Result="exists"
    Variable="UsbDriversInstalled" />
```

You should also add a `DetectCondition="UsbDriversInstalled = 1"` to your EXE_UsbDriversInstallerExe `<ExePackage>` This will stop you from trying to double install this product.

Create a second `<ExePackage>`.

```
<ExePackage
    Id="EXE_UsbDriversUninstallerExe"
    DetectCondition="NOT WixBundleInstalled OR UsbDriversInstalled = 1"
    UninstallCommand="whatever the uninstall command is"
    SourceFile="[ProgramFilesFolder]\SomeThirdPartyCompany\Drivers-Installed\Uninstall.exe"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Cache="no"
    Compressed="no" />
```

So now you will always have the Uninstall.exe 'installed' and you can uninstall this ExePackage when uninstalling the bundle because it has an UninstallCommand.

Comment: This answers works, but I had to change the [ProgramFilesFolder] of the SourceFile to the actual full path e.g. "c:\Program Files (x86)\SomeThirdPartyCompany\.." in the "EXE_UsbDriversUninstallerExe" package declaration.

Comment: This answers works, but I had to change the [ProgramFilesFolder] of the SourceFile to the actual full path e.g. "c:\Program Files (x86)\SomeThirdPartyCompany\.." in the "EXE_UsbDriversUninstallerExe" package declaration. The reason being that I was getting "System cannot find the file [ProgramFilesFolder]\SomeThirdPartyCompany\Drivers-Isntaller\Uninstall.exe" when I was generating a Bundle project build.  For some reason, the ProgramFilesFolder value isn't being found.  Any ideas how to resolve this ?

Comment: That is weird, I got that value from the build-in wix burn variables page here:  http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html

Comment: I used this because on a 32-bit maching the "C:\Program Files (x86)" folder just doesn't exist so it is not very safe to hard code that value in. Hope you can figure out why the variable for this folder isn't working out.

Comment: Worth mentioning that instead of adding `DetectCondition="UsbDriversInstalled = 1"` to the existing ExePackage, I needed to add `InstallCondition="UsbDriversInstalled = 0"` (notice reverse condition).

Comment: How is it supposed to work? When I try to uninstall the bundle, the pop-up appears and it asks me to indicate Uninstall.exe file.

Comment: It also requires to have Uninstall.exe on the machine where the bundle is created, right?

Comment: This method doesn't work. as @Chris said you need to have uninstall file at the time of bundle creation.